# Stored Procedure to get all records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to loop thru all the records and concatenate them into one string.

Here is the code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_GET_TRACKING_NOS
  (
    P_ORDERID NUMBER,
    TRACKINGNOS OUT VARCHAR2
  )
IS
  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT TRACKID
    FROM MULTISHIPDTL
    WHERE ORDERID = P_ORDERID;
BEGIN
  TRACKINGNOS := '';

  FOR TRACKID_REC IN C1
  LOOP
    TRACKINGNOS := TRACKINGNOS + ', ' + TRACKID_REC.TRACKID;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE P_GET_TRACKING_NOS
  (
    P_ORDERID NUMBER,
    TRACKINGNOS OUT VARCHAR2
  )
IS
  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT TRACKID
    FROM MULTISHIPDTL
    WHERE ORDERID = P_ORDERID;
BEGIN
  TRACKINGNOS := '';

  FOR TRACKID_REC IN C1
  LOOP
    TRACKINGNOS := TRACKINGNOS + ', ' + TRACKID_REC.TRACKID;
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: String concatenation in oracle is ||  not +.  I hope your output is not greater than 32K, as that is the limit for VARCHAR2 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how long the result is, and if it is shorter than 4000 characters, a simpler option would be to use `LISTAGG`, e.g.

```
select listagg(m.trackid, ', ') within group (order by null) result
from multishipdtl m
where m.orderid = p_orderid;
```

Besides, why is it a *procedure*? A **function** seems to be a better option (you can use it in SQL; a procedure with an `OUT` parameter requires a(n anonymous) PL/SQL block, declaring a variable which accepts the result). For example:

```
create or replace function f_get_tracking_nos (p_orderid in number)
  return varchar2
is
  retval varchar2(4000);
begin
  select listagg(m.trackid, ', ') within group (order by null)
    into retval
    from multishipdtl m
    where m.orderid = p_orderid;

  return retval;
end;
```